# Here Map Javascript SDK run in Angular App for phone, But the performance is so bad. How to improve performance on phone device (iPhone 6)?

Tags: here-api

Even open one map on iPhone 6, it is so slow, and every 10 seconds make system refreshing page once.
Normal default Map:

```
  constructor() {
    this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'apikey': API_Key
    });

   }

public ngAfterViewInit() {
 let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
      this.mapHere = new H.Map(
          this.mapElement.nativeElement,
          defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, //3.1
          // defaultLayers.normal.map,  //3.0
          {
              zoom: 16,
              center: this.center,
              pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
          }
      );
......
}
```

Comment: Can you please help with some more details like is this the only map loading JS that being used, are there some other heavy DOMS ?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure optimum performance on mobile devices, add the following meta-tag to the `<head>` section of the HTML page:

> < meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" >

check the link for more information.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html